# Как правильно создавать рекламные баннеры в admob?

Tags: admob

У меня в приложении на разных экранах есть баннеры с рекламой. Нужно ли создавать для каждого окна отдельный баннер на сайте admob с уникальным идентификатором или же создать один и размещать его на всех экранах? И как тот или иной вариант скажется на доходах?

Comment: А какая цель? Например необходимо ли отслеживать эффективность показов на каждом экране? будете ли както на каждом экране менять параметры показа?

Comment: @SergeMarkov параметры показа не меняю, эффективность показов не важна, важно узнать именно доходы от двух способов.

Comment: Можно и не создавать уникальный банер, дело в том что при оплате какого-то продукта вы можете отслеживать что покупака совершена.
так вот для того чтоб собрать аналитику дохода , вы можете использовать Firebase -> GoogleAnalytics там можете помтку поставить с какого окна или списка была осуществлена оплата, в статистке по Event можно сделать фильтрацию. Если не ошибасюь в AdMob где-то и предлагается работать именно с FireBase

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei я знаю про firebase и googleAnalytics. Интересно узнать именно про заработок, так как не совсем с этим разобрался. Он будет больше, если для каждого окна отдельный баннер или же если один баннер для всех окон? Или же разницы не будет?

Comment: @SviatoIa а в этом вопрос, не так понял. Будет разница в зависиомсти от компании самих банеров естетсвенно, если она будет идентична, то не будет разницы.

Comment: @ShwarzAndrei получается стоимость просмотров фиксирована, зависит только от компании и не рассчитывается исходя из популярности баннера в приложении? Что такое тогда доход на тысячу показов и почему он периодически меняется?